# How to save JSON string information to one overall name

Tags: python, json, string

i am using Python combined with JSON.

I basically want my Python code to print out all information of a string by just saying for example print(profile1)

Here is the JSON File which includes 3 different profile, splitted into a string.

String 1 = Profile1

String 2= Profile2

String 3= Profile3

```
[
  {
    "guid": "1f1c4ac7-fc36-4008-935b-d87ffc7d8700",
    "isActive": false,
    "name": {
      "first": "Reid",
      "last": "Warren"
    },
    "email": "reid.warren@undefined.name",
    "phone": "+1 (983) 443-3504",
    "address": "359 Rapelye Street, Holtville, Marshall Islands, 9692"
  },
  {
    "guid": "0a661c22-ce39-40fb-bcb1-742028cc0c9e",
    "isActive": true,
    "name": {
      "first": "Amelia",
      "last": "Wilkinson"
    },
    "email": "amelia.wilkinson@undefined.us",
    "phone": "+1 (831) 563-3240",
    "address": "525 Allen Avenue, Iola, Kentucky, 894"
  },
  {
    "guid": "e23bbe57-7f46-4e03-9f72-0d7499d96153",
    "isActive": false,
    "name": {
      "first": "Shari",
      "last": "Sullivan"
    },
    "email": "shari.sullivan@undefined.ca",
    "phone": "+1 (922) 472-2774",
    "address": "366 Leonora Court, Cecilia, Pennsylvania, 3333"
  }
]
```

Now i want my python code to print out all informations of the selected Profile (first. last, email, phone, address) when i say for example print(Profile1)

This is my current code which prints out all the first names, so not for example just of Profile1

```
import json

class User:
    def __init__(self, guid, isActive, name, email, phone, address):
        self.guid = guid
        self.isActive = isActive
        self.first_name = name['first']
        self.last_name = name['last']
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.address = address

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_string):
        json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        return cls(**json_dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f' { self.first_name }'



users_list = []
with open('Data1.json', 'r') as json_file:
    user_data = json.loads(json_file.read())
    for u in user_data:
        users_list.append(User(**u))

print(users_list)
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Is it really your code? The code was apparently written by an experienced programmer and the question is so trivial. Anyway, what profile data is printed is defined in `__repr__()` and to select a profile simply use an index, e.g. `print(users_list[0])`.

Comment: Yeah its half/half from me, i found it and took some elements of that to my script. Yeah i knew that but how can i connect a name to the String? Like print(Profile1) and then it prints all the information of Profile 1 ( String1) out? So that not line or String i connected to the print but a name

Comment: The JSON stores a list of profiles. A list can have an arbitrary length in general. So, unless the number of profiles is fixed to exactly 3 by some specification it is a bad idea to have deidcated variables `profile1`, `profile2`, .etc. Currently  `users_list[N-1]` corresponds to ProfileN (because indices start with 0, not 1)